# Web View - Playback requires user action - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, web, swift2

Web View - Playback Requires User Action - in Swift

Hi there.

In my Main Storyboard I have a Web View, that is triggered by a button.

When the button is pressed, it pops up a music video from Youtube. When I then press the “Play-button” in this Youtube view, the song is played, meaning I have visuals and audio :-)

Under the Web View Options, there is a checkbox called "Playback Requires User Action”.In the help explanation it says:

“mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction
Property
A Boolean value that determines whether HTML5 videos can play automatically or require the user to start playing them.
Declaration
SWIFT
var mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction: Bool
Discussion
The default value on both iPad and iPhone is YES. To make media play automatically when loaded, set this property to NO and ensure the  or  element you want to play has the autoplay attribute set.”

What does "autoplay attribute set” mean ?

I want this music video played, without pressing the “Play-button” in the Youtube view ? Is this even possible ?

Have searched, but found nothing.

I'm a novice and can’t figure out, how to do this.

Does anyone have a clue ? :-)

It would be highly appreciated.

Ola